# Dell XPS 9300 Running Ubuntu 20.04: screen goes blank for 2 seconds whenever there is media on chromium or a notification sound

Tags: dell, screen, xps

I have the new Dell XPS 9300 running Ubuntu 20.04 and when I first boot up in the morning, certains things like video on reddit as I scroll down, or Discord/Telegram/Skype notifcation bells cause the screen to go black for 2 seconds.

I contacted Dell support and they had me run a diagnostic which came back fine. They said they can't help me with the OS>

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

I am no longer seeing these issues. I updated all of my software including firmware via "Ubuntu Software". My current firmware version is "1.0.7". I'm not certain this was the fix.

Original:

This is only a stop-gap solution that I'm using for now. You can try disabling the audio output in your BIOS and use bluetooth or USB headphones instead.

Here's an extra detail about they symptoms I saw. Whenever a notification would come along, the screen would go black for two seconds and the audio wouldn't play until the screen came back on.

Comment: Yup. exactly what I'm seeing. Unfortunately Dell's overseas tech support is useless.